# Properties inheriting in org doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, text-properties

I have this sample org file:

```
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %TODO %5owner %3PRIORITY %TAGS
* test1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :owner:    own1
  :END:
** test2
** test3
```

I also have in my .emacs file:
`(setq org-use-property-inheritance (quote ("owner")))`

Why the "owner" property is not inherited to headings "test2" and "test3"?
In column view the column "owner" is empty for above headings:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/b2D6bhC.png]

I also tried (without success):

1. .emacs file: `(setq org-use-property-inheritance t)`
2. changing `:owner:` in the "test1" drawer to `:owner_ALL:`
3. using file property: `#+PROPERTY: owner_ALL own1`

Comment: For me the property for these subsequent entries is defined as you can verify using `C-c / p`, but appears not to be picked by the column view, the `v` command shows a blank on the lower entries.

Comment: The sparse tree works correctly for me too. Maybe someone knows how to force column view into showing inherited properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the under-development version of org-mode, per the thread at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/98091.